# Working with files

Tags: java

I'm working on a project right now , and there are functions defined to write and read from file , my particular problem is about not having a format while text files are being read by the system , here are these two functions to write and read from files;

```
public void writetofile()
{
    String bucky4[]={custname,custlname,agee,address,id};
    for(int i = 0; i < bucky4.length; i++) {
         try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new     FileWriter("records.txt", true))) {
             String s;
             s = bucky4[i];
             bw.write(s);
             bw.newLine();
             bw.flush();
         }

         catch(IOException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In File");
         }
     }
}

public void filereader (){

     int i=0;
     Object[] options = {"OK"};
     try{
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
         String strLine;
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

         while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
         {
             sb.append(strLine +"\n");
         }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
     }catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers",  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
     }
  };
```

right now my out put is like this :

> `james` 
>   `blunt` 
>   `male`  
>   `18`    
>   `c-18-6 , kombo`

and I'm looking forward to make them in a proper format like this :

> `first name : james` 
>  
>   `last name : blunt`  
>   `gender : male` ;...

please do consider that I can't use constructors , any help is appreciated

Comment: `"please do consider that I can't use constructors"`? Why not? Is it against religious principles?

Comment: hahah , what made you say that :D , no it's like there are many files i'm using , this one I've copied above is about customers , I do have around 8 files having many things in them ,

Comment: Who is this guys `custname,custlname,agee,address,id` on this array `String bucky4[]={custname,custlname,agee,address,id};`

Comment: All religion aside, what does your input file look like?  If you can guarantee that everything comes in the exact same order every time, you can just hard code it, as in Henry's example.  That's a pretty big if, though.

Comment: Any other solution , henry codes ends up with an error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I've defined an array and a simple if and else and it's solved , here are the segments of codes :

```
        public void filereader (){
        String[] titles = {"first name: ", "last name: ", "gender" ,"age","address","id"};
        int i=0;
        Object[] options = {"OK"};
        try
        {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
       {
        sb.append(titles[i]+ strLine +"\n");
              if (i == 5) { 
                   i=0;
               } else
               { i++; };
                 }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
               }catch(Exception e){
              JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers",   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
               }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always in the same order (First name, last name, gender...), you could make a function that would format your output string using `StringTokenzier` to spilt the data by '\n' character. Then you could append each line to a `StringBuffer` with `"first name"`, `"last name"`, `"gender"`, etc. and then return the result.

```
public String format(String s){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "\n");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("first name : " + st.nextToken() + '\n');
    sb.append("last name : " + st.nextToken() + '\n');
    sb.append("gender : " + st.nextToken() + '\n');
    ...
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hey Henry , when I type down your function it ends up giving me an error saying: no suitable constructor found for String Tokenizer(String , Char) and it's say that string tokenizer is not applicable

Comment: @Jessie It should be `new StringTokenizer(s, "\n")`. That's according to the API doc which anybody can check (including you): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Jessie Radiodef is right, you need to replace new StringTokenizer(s, '\n'), with new StringTokenizer(s, "\n").